# SQL "substr" combine with "not in"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table(ne) with this elements:

```
LECOT113_A42401
DA_RIMUOVERE
TVCCVC16_A46C01
CBCELEN1_A46C01
SPCBA440_A46C02
582
ghhtthth
TESTVMM
SACCALEN_A46C0da_cancellare
MICTEST
DA_CANCELLARE2
```

and i use this query:

```
select  ne.NODE     
from    ne
where   substr(ne.NODE,9,2) not in ('_A')
```

why result is:

```
DA_RIMUOVERE
DA_CANCELLARE2
```

and not this (TARGET):

```
582
DA_RIMUOVERE582
ghhtthth
TESTVMM
SACCALEN_A46C0da_cancellare
MICTEST
DA_CANCELLARE2
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess `SACCALEN_A46C0da_cancellare` should not be in the results.

Comment: Your result must **not** contain these values, right? Because all of them have `_A` at the 9th position.

Comment: Yes, but outside the list must remain only these:
LECOT113_A42401
TVCCVC16_A46C01
CBCELEN1_A46C01
SPCBA440_A46C02
I updated the result

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Return all record with this pattern:
max length "not 15" and substr start 9 length 2 not "_A"
So outside the list must remain only these: LECOT113_A42401 TVCCVC16_A46C01 CBCELEN1_A46C01 SPCBA440_A46C02 with length always 15 and substr 9,2 = _A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) returns `null` when the starting position is greater than the length of the string, so comparing `null` to `'_A'` gives wrong results.
So change to this:

```
select  ne.NODE     
from    ne
where   length(ne.NODE) < 9 or length(ne.NODE) <> 15 or substr(ne.NODE,9,2) not in ('_A')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a7d4fb7604bb636affc3166df8d54e3).
Results:

```
> | NODE                        |
> | :-------------------------- |
> | DA_RIMUOVERE                |
> | 582                         |
> | ghhtthth                    |
> | TESTVMM                     |
> | SACCALEN_A46C0da_cancellare |
> | MICTEST                     |
> | DA_CANCELLARE2              |
```

Comment: I would change `<9` into `<10`. For the rest, perfect answer

Comment: Correct, since the substring takes 2 chars.

Comment: Good but i would to exclude also this:
SACCALEN_A46C0da_cancellare

Comment: It is excluded, check the results

Comment: sorry, i would to include SACCALEN_A46C0da_cancellare

Comment: it work also without "length(ne.NODE) < 9", query:
(length(ne.NODE) <> '15' or substr(ne.NODE,9,2) not in  ('_A'))
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact in SQL NULL neither true not false. In your case some of your string has length less then 9, so substr(...) return NULL. Value of NULL not in (...) is NULL.

Additional information can be found on [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=not-in-operator-with-null-data)

So, just rewrite condition on something like

```sql
select  ne.NODE     
from    ne
where   nvl(substr(ne.NODE,9,2),'x') not in ('_A')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Oracle confuses the empty string (`''`) and `NULL` values.  So, the substring returns `NULL` -- and then most comparisons return `NULL` rather than false.

One method would use `LIKE`:

```
where ne.NODE not like '_________$_A%' escape '$'
```

Or `regexp_like()`:

```
where regexp_like(ne.NODE, '^.{9}_A')
```

Or being sure that the string is long enough:

```
where substr(ne.NODE || 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 9, 2) not in ('_A')
```

Or checking for the length as well as the patter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    NODE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            NE.NODE,
            SUBSTR(NE.NODE, 9, 2) SUBST
        FROM
            NE
    )
WHERE
    SUBST <> '_A'
    OR SUBST IS NULL
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d5f8ce93b0c1acafd038f2ea055e5d70)

Cheers!!